# Get and set bundle-idenfitier of my app during run time

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-foundation

I'm trying to get the `CFBundleIdentifier` value of my app on run time. Using either Is this possible? I searched `NSApplication` class reference but I can't find something that gives me the bundle identifier.

Am also interested in setting the `bundle-identifier` during run time please, can this be done?

Thanks

PS: I know this is a weird question if you don't know the context, as an app has one bundle identifier. However users launch my app (build of Firefox) through their on `.app` and shell command which gives it their `.app`'s bundle identifier. More details on the context here: [ask.m.o :: OSX - How to control the bundle-identifier and file-data :: _CFURLString](https://ask.mozilla.org/question/1425/osx-how-to-control-the-bundle-identifier-and-file-data-_cfurlstring/) The `[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]` is not giving me the bundle identifier of the launching `.app`. I also tried iterating through all of the `[[NSBundle allBundles] bundleIdentifier]` but it wasn't in there either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the bundle identifire Is not possible. Even if you do some nasty digg, it will be rejected from appstore.

As for obtaining it, use :

[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];

Comment: Thanks for this I forgot to mention this doesn't work. Because of my context, a .app is launching my build of Firefox via shell. So mainBundle identifier will definitely be the Firefox string of `org.mozilla.firefox`. I'm trying to get that bundle info of that `.app`

Comment: PS: I also tried iterating through `allBundles` and none of them had the idnentifier of the launcing app, which is what im trying to get because if the user does right click and say "keep in dock" the `bundle-identifier` in the `/Users/noit/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist` gets set to that.

Comment: What about setting the bundleIdentifier during the startup phases of the app? Is that possible? No problem about the app store. My stuff is free open source stuff. :)

Comment: I accepted answer, but need is still there to get the the `bundle-identifier` that is the same as that gets written to `com.apple.dock.plist` :(

Comment: `[[NSRunningApplication currentApplication] bundleIdentifier]` gave the correct one. Do you know why? Verified that `[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]` continue to give the identifier of the `Firefox.app` not the `dev.app` launcher "shortcut".

Comment: Well, mainBundle is the bundle data from the the context app that is runing (since you are asking it from firefox it will be firefox bundle id); 

While the [NSRunningApplication currentApplication] bundle is the bundle of the currently running app on. And you can retrieve only bundle Identifiers from this one, Other properties may vary over time, such as whether the app is hidden or not.

Basically it differs in the context you are getting the identifiers.

Comment: Thanks Timur! When I listed all bundles via NSBundle though, the `NSRunningApplication currentApplication bundleIdentifier` didn't show, that was very interesting